# MySQL statement to pivot table without using pivot function or a union

Tags: mysql

Without using the pivot/unpivot function or a union, is it possible to change this data:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | name   | surname |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | john   | smith   |
| 2  | jack   | brown   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

into this:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | data        |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | john        |
| 1  | smith       |
| 2  | jack        |
| 2  | brown       |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: This generates code (based on your table schema) to do the task:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a cursor

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `p`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
begin 
    declare vid int(8);
    declare vname varchar(15);
    declare vsurname varchar(15);
    declare done int default 0;
    declare cname cursor for select id,name,surname from t id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cname;
    cursorloop:loop
    fetch cname into vid,vname,vsurname;
    if done = true then  
        leave cursorloop;
    end if;  
    insert into t1 (id,name) select vid,vname;
    insert into t1 (id,name) select vid,vsurname;
    end loop cursorloop;
    close cname;
end $$
delimiter ;

drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t( id int, name varchar(20), surname varchar(20));
create table t1(id int, name varchar(20));
insert into t values
( 1  , 'john'   , 'smith'),
( 2  , 'jack'   , 'brown');

call p();

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t1;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | john  |
|    1 | smith |
|    2 | jack  |
|    2 | brown |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But why would you not use a union?

Comment: I'm working with a really really big database and a union is too inefficient to use since it takes a very long time to give me a result.

Answer (score 0):

Use cross join and case statement to either get name or surname.

```
select rn as id, (case when  id=rn then name else surname end) as `data`
from
(
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.surname, t2.rn
from myTable t1
cross join (
   select surname, (@r2:=@r2+1) as rn 
   from myTable, (select @r2:= 0) r) t2
) tab

Result:
id  data
1   jon
1   smith
2   brown
2   jack
```