# How Do I convert this table from row to column?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have a table that contains id and country name, and I need to convert them so the id with more than 1 country will display in 1 row.I have been searching in this forum for over an hour and found nothing.

I tried if using the pivot function can help me to achieve the result i wanted, but I feel like using pivot does not work on my case here.

This is a mini version of the table I have. The number of distinct value in the field "country" will be over 100, so I can just say something like when county = '..' as this will be to repetitive.

```
enter code here
 +----+--------+
| id | country|
+----+--------+
| 1  | US     |
| 1  | UK     |
| 2  | JP     |
+----+--------+
```

Desired outcome I am looking for:

```
enter code here

+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | country_1 | country_2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | US        |   UK      |
| 2  | JP        |   null    |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I found this question which is similar but it is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve.

[MySQL statement to pivot table without using pivot function or a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553644/mysql-statement-to-pivot-table-without-using-pivot-function-or-a-union)

---

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
update:

Thank you so much for all of your helps. I may not have used the queries of yours to solve my problem - as of the fact that the syntax is a bit diff running in snowflake. However, I got the insights I need from all of you.

here is my solution:

```
enter code here
select t1.id,
max(iff(t1.row_number = 1, t1.country ,null)) as country_1,
max(iff(t1.row_number = 2, t1.country ,null)) as country_2,
max(iff(t1.row_number = 3, t1.country, null)) as country_3
from
(
  select id, country, row_number() over (partition by id order by id ) as 
row_number
  from table
) t1
group by t1.id
```

Comment: Is there always 2 country per id?

Comment: No, in my case the max is 3. So an id could have either 2 or 3 countries assigned to it, and I have many many ids and over 100 different country names.

Comment: Be aware that `ROW_NUMBER()` and `OVER` require MySQL 8 or MariaDB.

Comment: My queries run in snowflake and it runs fine. Thanks.

Comment: I think if I have more than 3 countries to append, store procedure might be the one to make the process more dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Whereas you could do it with "pivoting", what will happen when you have 3 countries?  Or 4?  Or 17?

May I suggest this:

```
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(country)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY id;
```

You will get something like:

```
1   US,UK
2   JP
```

Comment: That works, though you changed the question a little bit ;)

Comment: Thanks. this kind of close to what i am trying to get. However, i do need the values to be in different column, and for each id, it could be assigned more than 2 countries. (max is 3 in my case)

Answer (score 2):

use aggregation

```
 select id, max(case when id=1 then country end ) as country_1,
 max(case when id=2 then country end ) as country_2
 from tbale group by id
```

Comment: The table I provided here is just a mini version, there will be many many ids in the column.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "dynamic" PIVOT in SQL. You need to specify the list of columns when writing the query. Your options are:

1. If you know the number of columns in advance, then @ZaynulAbadinTuhin solution is the easier. It seems, however, this is not your case.
2. If you don't know the number of columns in advance and you want them all concatenated in a single column, then @Rick James solution is the best.
3. Otherwise, you can still use some kind of dynamic SQL in your app or in a stored procedure that will build the SQL query at runtime, based on the existing values of the table. But this solution would require much more programming. It's not a single/simple SQL query anymore. See [Rick James's Pivoting in MySQL](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) stored procedure.

Comment: Base on Rick James' answers, i think I can try to group the string together and then use regexp_substr to separate them into different column - not sure if it can be done.

Comment: Well, my pivot-builder may come close to a "dynamic" pivot:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: @RickJames Holy guacamole. That's kind of awesome!

Comment: @TheImpaler - Thanks.  I thrive on "Tackling Tough Table Tasks".  You may have noticed the list of things (at the end of the blog) that I have tackled.  I've temporarily run out of challenges; do you have another one for me?

Answer (score 1):

As you comment on @Rick answer you have max 3 country for each id then you can use this

```
select 
id,
(select country from test  where test.id=t.id limit 0,1)as country_1,
(select country from test where test.id=t.id limit 1,1)as country_2,
(select country from test where test.id=t.id limit 2,1)as country_3
from test as t
group by id;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fgBRFi84KzuoANHVU1keAw/0)

Comment: This is very nice, but I am running the query in Snowflake and it keeps giving me this error. Any suggestion?                                                                                         
"syntax error line 3 at position 1 unexpected 'select'.
syntax error line 3 at position 115 unexpected ','"

Comment: @MichaelZeng I really don't know about snowflake but I tested it on various online compiler it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this following script with RowNumber generated per id. As you confirmed there are maximum 3 country per id, we can easily generate your desired result set by handling RowNumber 1,2 & 3

```
SELECT ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN country ELSE NULL END) Country_1,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN country ELSE NULL END) Country_2,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 3 THEN country ELSE NULL END) Country_3
FROM
(
    SELECT id, 
    country,
    @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = concat_ws('',id),@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
    ,@prev_value := concat_ws('',id)
    FROM tbale
    ORDER BY id
)A 
GROUP BY id
```